# Stackoverflow DB structure - Have a similar situation on the tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database-design

is stackoverlow database structure available somewhere?

I am facing a situation where I have Table1 with information about something and Table2 with numeric information about Table1 on a 1:n relatioship. Like we have users and answers here on stack overflow for example.

I need to have quick access to the sum of the numeric information (like S.O. has quick access to the user's reputation sum) and I'm wondering if I add a column on Table1 to store the sum and update it everytime table2 is updated or if I sum all records on table2 every time I need that Info.

S.O. has the same situation and seems to be dealing very well with it. I would like to know which approach do they use.

Comment: Have a look at the right side: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new or here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-data-explorer

Comment: @Tim SEDE isn't *quite* exactly the same, always, as the operational data

Comment: yeah, what is that? Its saying that my last access date is 2012-03-13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we denormalize that into a database field that we update over time. We *used* to do recalcs (it would drift occasionally) by performing the join / sum, but that hurts - and we didn't like it being out of sync in the first place. So now, we keep a *specific* store for reputation changes over time - more direct and accurate history.

Comment: cool, but the refresh is pretty fast, I mean the refresh interval should be only a few seconds.. I don't think you run for every user every time. Do you have a mechanism to run for a smaller group of users for example? Like only refresh "logged" users for example?

Answer (score 0):

Your situation is *not* defined by the realtionship in SO between posts, replies and rep. You have a totally generic database situation where you need to sum values associated with a header record.

You have hot upon the 2 usual ways to solve this requirement

1. Sum the values using the aggregation methods available to SQL when you need the value
2. Sum the values as new rows are added, and store it against the header

Both have pros and cons, but there is mainly 1 weigh-up to consider

1. Data integrity maintained (pro), performance hindered (con)
2. Data corruption possible (con), performance not hindered (pro)

Comment: thanks Jamiec, I'm aware of the pros and cons and yo uare right about them, but my question was how does S.O. does it? because it seems to be doing a very good job.